# Elequent queries on the 'many' table in a one-to-many ralationship

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have an address table and a residents table joined in a one-to-many way such that the query

```
House::with('resident')->where('postcode', 'GL141PQ')->get();
```

would return something like this

```
[{
    "id": 806,
    "code": "AYC8rk",
    "postcode": "GL141PQ",
    "address": "THE COTTAGE, ADSETT COURT, LONDON ",
    "resident": [{
        "id": 5441,
        "firstname": "THOMAS",
        "surname": "MARSHALL"
    }, {
        "id": 5442,
        "firstname": "ANNA",
        "surname": "RAYMOND"
    }, {
        "id": 6188,
        "firstname": "WILL",
        "surname": "MARSHALL"
    }]
}]
```

If there are lots of properties in that postcode and I need to extend the query to include the surname in the Residents table I am stumped. The below obviously doesn't work so I assume I need to iterate through the joined table somehow.

```
House::with('resident')
->where('postcode', 'GL141PQ', 'and')
->where('surname', 'MARSHALL')
->get();
```

Any help very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Laravel's `with()` like this is just lazy loading the residents onto your House model, it's not joining it.

You can probably do something like this (untested):

```
House::with(['resident' => function($query) use ($surname) {
       $query->where('surname', $surname);
   }])
   ->where('postcode', 'GL141PQ')
   ->get();
```

---

Edit:

Then you'll have to add the join yourself. As said the with() is lazy loading, not joining.

```
House::with('resident') // lazy load all residents after query is done, you don't want to filter here
    ->leftJoin('resident', 'house.id', '=', 'resident.house_id')
    ->where('resident.surname', $surname)
    ->where('house.postcode', 'GL141PQ')
    ->groupBy('house.id')
    ->get();
```

or

```
House::with('resident') // lazy load all residents after query is done, you don't want to filter here
    ->leftJoin('resident', function($join) use ($surname) {
        $join->on('house.id', '=', 'resident.house_id')
            ->where('resident.surname', $surname)
    })
    ->where('house.postcode', 'GL141PQ')
    ->groupBy('house.id')
    ->get();
```

Those will give you the results you need.

Keep in mind that Laravel's `->count()` and `->groupBy(x)` don't like each other that much.

Comment: Thanks Robert. It works great but I think I may have explained it slightly ambiguously. Your code returns all the houses in the postcode with only the requested surnames eager loaded. What I need is to return the complete records with all the surnames but only where at least one surname matches. So for the original example it would return exactly as it for `surname = 'MARSHALL'` or `surname = 'RAYMOND'` and nothing for `surname = 'JONES'`. Thanks again. –

Comment: Thanks Robert, they both work perfectly. I really appreciate your help. As a matter of interest would one of those solutions perform better than the other? I am assuming that lazy loading is the preferred solution otherwise?

Comment: Well it more or less depends on if the above is the complete query. You would have to benchmark them. Though in general for left joins (outer joins), there is a difference compared to using inner joins, due to the amount of rows you need.